# Trying to get IQR with groupby data

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I'm new to Python. I'm trying to create a basic set of descriptive stats (min, max, IQR, etc.).

I snipped some code to help me get to where I am, but it is a bit more complicated since I've used groupby:

```
Causesofdeathbyyear = deathdata.groupby(['Year','Causes of Death'])
```

When I try to do a simple difference between one quartile range and another, I'm getting an error.

[image]

Comment: It's better to paste the error as part of your question. It helps the fellow developers with the same issue to find your question easily.

Comment: You really be posting the code/error as text in a codeblock so that people can 1) read it more easily, 2) copy/paste to test if necessary an 3) more easily find later when searching...

Comment: Thank you both for your feedback. I'm new, so I appreciate the guidance.

Answer (score 2):

You should just be passing `IQR` instead of `IQR()`

Here is a similar example:

```
In[1]: import pandas as pd

In[2]: import numpy as np

In[3]: data = pd.DataFrame({"A": np.random.random_integers(0, 100, 100), "Year": np.random.random_integers(2000, 2015, 100)})

In[4]: grouped_by_year = data.groupby("Year")

In[5]: def mm_diff(x):
           return np.max(x) - np.min(x)

In[6]: grouped_by_year["A"].agg([np.sum, mm_diff])
Out[6]: 
      sum  mm_diff
Year              
2000  465       78
2001  277       72
2002  242       76
2003  390       78
2004  755       82
2005  495       92
2006  174       78
2007  189       54
2008  359       78
2009  139       66
2010  139       41
2011  406       77
2012  309       66
2013  123       50
2014  295       75
2015  295       92
```

Comment: Thanks Kapil, I tried that and it didn't work. It gave an error too long to paste here. I tried to edit the original comment but it said my code wasn't formatted properly. This is too much work to figure out on this interface to paste (and they didn't like when I added an image), so I'll just pass on finding a solution here.